# Placeholders in properties file are not replaced in target by maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I have a filter.properties file that contains the following :

```
database.driver= mydatabase
database.url= myURL
database.user=usr
database.password=pwd
database.initialsize=3
database.maxactive=5
```

I also have this in my openejb.xml file in a Resource tag :

```
JdbcDriver ${database.driver}
JdbcUrl ${database.url}
UserName ${database.user}
Password ${database.password}
```

But when I do a tomee:run with maven I get a ton of errors of this type :

```
Unable to resolve class ${database.driver}
```

OR

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${database.driver}
```

I've tried to counter the problem by adding in my pom.xml :

```
<properties>
<myDatabase.driver>${database.driver}</myDatabase.driver>
</properties>
```

But it didn't work.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Set

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

This assumes everything is a resource, file on the class path.

Alternatively create such a data source outside of the application in Tomcat.