# how to get parameter value from pom.xml via config.properties

Tags: java, maven, configuration

I want to receive the link specified in a `pom.xml` through a `config.properties`

I have:

```
<properties>
         <site_url>https://biz-trunk.rts-tender.ru/</site_url>
</properties>
```

in `pom.xml`,

```
site_url = ${site_url}
```

in `config.properties`,

```
private Properties properties = new Properties();
public void loadConfig() {
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(getPropertiesFileName());
        properties.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to download config and this

[image]

Why???

[image]

Why is it not working???

Comment: Without the full `pom.xml` it's impossible to tell whether or not you're actually using a plugin that populates your config file, and even if you are, it might not play nice with your IDE

Comment: Are you writing a maven plugin? There's an easy way to [Configure properties](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html).

Comment: Presumably what you're trying to do is make your maven properties available to your java application. Are you using the resource plugin for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366129/placeholders-in-properties-file-are-not-replaced-in-target-by-maven ? Spring boot also has documentation on this, if you are using boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven has concept of [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). During build Maven will replace all available placeholders which look like `${some_text}` with corresponding properties' values from pom.xml. If no property found then value will not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

In the `loadConfig()` at the entrance must be path `config.properties` which after assembly is created in the `target/`.